# Difference between Module and plugin in Petrel Ocean

Tags: plugins

I started to touch Petrel Ocean just now, and what to know what is the difference between the Plug-in and the Module.

At least for now, they look the same.

Can anyone please give me some ideas?

Comment: Despite the answers, this question is not a good fit for SO.

Answer (score 1):

Plugin is new, IModule is old.

Plugin Manager deals with Plugin so that is the one you should use.

Answer (score 1):

The Plugin class contains properties which provide identity to the plugin and used by plug-in manager. Plugin contains all Modules in IEnumerable Modules. The IModule interface defines methods of the module lifecycle phases. During the Petrel startup, the Ocean Core will load modules as defined in a configuration file by plug-in manager based on Plugin class.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to deploy your plug-in through the Ocean Store then you will be required to derive from the Plugin class. Of course your plug-in MUST also implement IModule since that is where the methods controlling the lifecycle reside.

Answer (score 0):

`Plugin` is an aggregating entity for `IModule`, i.e. one Ocean plug-in may consist of several modules, each of them licensed separately.

`Plugin` contains additional information - `Author`, `Contact`, `PluginUri`, which helps Petrel to inform users better, when a plug-in causes an issue (e.g. unhandled exception). By the way, `Plugin` is an information container only, as it does not contain any methods to override.

`Plugin` lets you declare `Dependencies`, to define the order of Ocean plug-ins loading in Petrel.

And finally, an Ocean plug-in with `Plugin` class defined and packaged as PIP, contains a metafile in XML format, with all the `Plugin` properties, letting Petrel to check for certain conditions upfront, without actually installing it. An example is `AppVersion` property, which define the version of host application (e.g. Petrel), that this plug-ins is compiled with.